# Maximum length of last line in paragraph

Tags: lengths

Is there a LaTeX parameter (e.g., a penalty parameter) or any complex solution that can be setup maximum length of the last line in the all paragraphs throughout the text? Let's say, 2 em horizontal white space at the end of a paragraph?

Manual addition of horizontal space at the end of the paragraph is not appropriate.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The question seem to have already appeared. If the answers to the linked question don't help you, please tell why in your question. It's a good one, by the way.